# A funny exercise using by for loop

Tags: php, for-loop, nested-loops

I am interested in the loop exercise and saw a funny questions as below shown.

- Create a script to construct the following pattern, using a nested for loop.
- For the implementation, please using "echo" and showed by the table form.

```
0 0 1 0 0
0 1 1 1 0
1 1 1 1 1
0 1 1 1 0
0 0 1 0 0
```

I try hard and coding an hour but I could not be succes and I can implement an triangle as

```
1 0 0 0 0
1 1 0 0 0
1 1 1 0 0
1 1 1 1 0
1 1 1 1 1
```

I understand my knowledge of martix and array is poor, I am pleased if anyone can teach me, thank you.

code of triangle loop:

```
    <?php 
        for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++){  
            for ($j=1;$j<=$i;$j++){  
                echo "1";  
            } 
            echo "</br>";  
        }
    ?>
```

Hello everyone, I had been completed the execrise by stupid way, thanks for everyone who helps me.

Here is my silly code:

```
for($i=1;$i<=$num;$i++){
  for($j=1;$j<=$num;$j++){  
    if($i==3||$j==3){  
      echo ' 1 ';
    }
    else if($i==$j-2){
      echo ' 1 ';
    }
    else if($j==$i-2){
      echo ' 1 ';
    }
    else if($i==2&&$j==2||$i==4&&$j==4){
      echo ' 1 ';
    }
    else{
      echo ' 0 ';
    }                 
  }   
    echo'<br>';   
}
```

Comment: It is adding 2's until it reaches 5 then it removes 2's till it reaches 1

Comment: Show what you've tried, not what you want to achieve. (*Quicker way of actually getting help.*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an option using [`str_pad()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) to pad the left and right side of the "ones" evenly. I'm using `implode()` and [`array_fill()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php) to create a string of ones that is the correct length to start with.

```
$size = 5;
// expanding
for($width = 1; $width <= $size; $width += 2) { // rows
    $ones = implode(array_fill(0, $width, '1'));
    echo str_pad($ones, $size, '0', STR_PAD_BOTH) . PHP_EOL;
}    

// contracting (exclude the first row where it's all ones
for($width = $size - 2; $width >= 1; $width -= 2) { // rows
    $ones = implode(array_fill(0, $width, '1'));
    echo str_pad($ones, $size, '0', STR_PAD_BOTH) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

For kicks, [here's another example](https://eval.in/172503) that only uses one loop.

---

**Note:** your specs say to use nested for loops - [CommuSoft's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24987712/2812842) fits that description nicely using math logic.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve most of these ASCII art puzzles by counting the different chars in each row, and try to generalize them.

For instance the first one:

> line 1: 2x0 1x1 2x0
>
> line 2: 1x0 3x1 1x0
>
> line 3: 0x0 5x1 0x0

Thus we generalize to:

> line i: (n/2-i)x0 2*i-1x1 (n/2-i)x0

Then you can implement this:

```
$n=5;
for ($i=1; $i<=$n/2+1; $i++) {
  for($j=0; $j<($n/2-$i); $j++) {
    echo '0 ';
  }
  for($j=0; $j<(2*$i-1); $j++) {
    echo '1 ';
  }
  for($j=0; $j<($n/2-$i); $j++) {
    echo '0 ';
  }
  echo "\n";
}
```

Try to implement the rest yourself.

Comment: A smart way to handle this task but I used the stupid way to finish it. Thanks a lot for help, Cheers!